# Indispensable system recovery applications to have in your toolbox?

Tags: partition-recovery, file-recovery, system-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the essential tools you always have handy when attempting to fix someone's PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/98423/what-are-the-essential-tools-you-always-have-handy-when-attempting-to-fix-someon)

What tools (software or hardware) have you found indispensable for recovering a failing PC?
What have you used in the past that has saved your bacon?   I'd like to know what else I can add to my arsenal.

I have a few such as [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) and [Ultimate BootCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some kind of Linux boot disk, with gparted, gpart and gnu ddrescue is invaluable. Some of the forensics tools for file carving can be good as a last resort. GetDataBack is very good as well. You might also want to keep copies of a few basic system files, like userinit.exe and ntldr, for when they get corrupted.

A couple of Windows install disks, for repairing installations of the different versions you support can be helpful. The System Rescue CD is also very good, it's got a load of useful Linux tools bundled into it.

Answer (score 4):

Linux live cd - i've used couple of times to confirm the hardware failures. Also it identified a corrupted NTFS drive which I couldn't do it using windows.

Answer (score 0):

**[SysClone](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sysclone/)** - some gentle soul combined the legendary **SytemRescueCD** with **Clonezilla** in a multi boot system (CD or USB)

[image]

(although the page is in German, the software is all English)