# Installing updates via Windows Live CD

Tags: windows-7

My computer bluesecreens a LOT (3 times just today), has been nearly since I built it 5 years ago and I've gone through everything to fix it. Last thing I've noticed is that there have been a couple of updates to my motherboard firmware but when I try to install them I just get an error that they won't work with a 64 bit OS (Windows 7 64).

I thought about using a live CD running a 32 bit Windows just to install the update. Anyone have any thoughts on this? Any reason it might not be a good idea? I looked around and just at first glance saw one called Vista pe that looked pretty decent.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your asking?  Please don't ask for our opinions... Ask if something is possible, and how you can make it happen.  That way the answer is clear and concrete.

Comment: how to solve the problem that my laptop no longer bluescreen?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/260043/how-do-i-troubleshoot-when-i-have-no-clue-where-to-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. work out *why* it bluescreens - I like nirsoft's [bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) for this
2. Run some tests - [memtestx86+](http://www.memtest.org/) would be a good strart.
3. If you're doing a bios update, these are often done from dos - which might be easier.

I'll update my answer, but 1 and 2 are *essential* for finding out how to make your laptop more stable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also find an installation CD and select upgrade, which then gives you the option to automatically install new updates in one of the pre-installation setup screens.

Comment: Before you do that though, I would advise that you deauthorize any installed software that relies on having only a certain amount of computers that are allowed to be on that same serial/account. Two that come to mind are any Rockstar games and also iTunes.