# Program to monitor another program

Tags: windows-7, process

Is it possible to monitor one program from/using another program.

Say, I want to monitor the responsiveness of a program or how much memory/cpu that process in using when doing a particular job. Is this possible?

I am not talking about monitoring task manager. I was looking for something more sophisticated method that could identify , what process or what subsystem is causing the ir-responsiveness for that program etc etc.

OS: Windows 7.

Comment: **Related:** See my answer to http://superuser.com/questions/404617/what-is-the-proper-way-of-debugging-a-slow-windows-installation, Process Monitor and Windows Performance Toolkit are essentials for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from MS

Comment: And how does PE help doing what the OP asked?

Comment: Agreed, should have said Process Monitor.