# Various parts of Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2013 get "blocked" by possibly common cause

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Everything started when I tried to open a project in Visual Studio 2013 and it freezed right after this was opened. Later, I found out that parts of Windows 8 aren't working either, like the firewall page in my control panel.

I had already seen this issue once before, but then I could solve it by goint to settings and check for updates. However, now this page doesn't do anything either (loading icon keeps rotating forever).

I have the feeling that there's a connection between these issues, like a common web service they all cannot access. Is there such a thing?

Of course, my network connection is up and running and a reboot didn't help.

**Update**

If found out that my second hard drive is not accessible anymore. Windows runs on an SSD, which is still working, but the pagefile is located on the HDD.

If I try to start up Windows after detaching the HDD, I get an error message. The reason for this might be that the `pagefile.sys` is located on the HDD. Unfortunately, I cannot open "System" inside my control panel; is there another way to reconfigure pagefile location?

**Update 2**

Running `chkdsk` results in no found errors, and I can even access the HDD in quesion via command line. It's just the explorer that freezes when I try to access it.

Comment: Maybe you did not solve the problem the first time around so now it appeared again. Maybe it is a Virus/Malware, bad configuration/modification, hardware problem, software problem and so on. Maybe check first if it is a Hardware problem: http://superuser.com/questions/404617/what-is-the-proper-way-of-debugging-a-slow-windows-installation

Comment: It's a hardware issue indeed! I'm not sure whether I should continue updating this question or create a new one...

Comment: You can open a new question with the gathered information and close this one. But always think how to make your question as specific as possible, otherwise you won't get answers. Also put all the things you already tried and as much information as possible. In Windows 8 you can refresh your OS without deleting anything did you know that ? It might solve a lot of things for you.

Comment: Thanks; yeah, I know that feature and it already saved me once on another machine. Regarding this one, I solved my problem, but still I'm not sure about the exact cause in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by changing the pagefile settings for it to be located on the main SSD instead of the HDD, then restarting my computer.

However, I'm not sure if the pagefile location was actually the reason, or an inconsistent state of Windows' fast reastarting feature in relation to the HDD. Reason for that thought is that usually I cannot access that HDD from Linux (on same machine, dual boot) unless I first start Windows, then reboot to Linux. More details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/329517/cant-access-my-hdd