# What’s the max RAM my computer will take?

Tags: memory

I have an Asus 1005HAB RBLU005S and need to add more memory. What’s the max RAM it will take?

Comment: It sounds like you have a number of questions: what is the max RAM, the ins&outs of an SSD, how to speed up a slow computer. Each should be a separate question. However, the SSD question is too broad. Super User focuses on specific questions rather than general learning on a topic. How to speed up a slow computer is also very broad because everything affects its speed.  If you use the search box at the top and look up slow computer, there are over 1400 answers.  This one will get you started: http://superuser.com/questions/404617/what-is-the-proper-way-of-debugging-a-slow-windows-installation.

Comment: I edited your question to focus on the main issue.  Please ask additional, specific questions you may have on the other topics after doing a little reading.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, the Asus eeePC line (which I believe that product number refers to) take up to 2GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're running Windows I would go to the [crucial website](http://www.crucial.com/) and use their free memory compatibility tool. It's a good download with no viruses or anything.  It doesn't install, it's just a temporary exe. The tool tells you system information. It tells you hard drives and how much ram you have and how much you can have and in which slots. I use it when friends ask me this question.